# Replace first child of <div> with replaceChild function

Tags: javascript

I'm writing simple table generator using JavaScript. I wrote function `createChild()` just like this:

```
function createTable(row_count, column_count) {
    var table = document.createElement("table"); 

    for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++) {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for (column = 0; column < column_count; column++) {
            let td = document.createElement("td"); 
            td.innerHTML = "a<sub>(" + (row+1) + "," + (column+1) + ")</sub>";
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    table.setAttribute("border", "1");

    var tableHolder = document.getElementById("table-container");
    var oldTable = tableHolder.firstChild;
    if (!oldTable) {
        tableHolder.appendChild(table);
    }
    else {
        tableHolder.firstChild.replaceWith(table);
        //tableHolder.replaceChild(tableHolder.firstChild, table);
    }
}
```

The problem occurs at these lines:

```
tableHolder.firstChild.replaceWith(table);
//tableHolder.replaceChild(tableHolder.firstChild, table);
```

If I use first line, It works alright but when I switch it to second line, It doesn't work with error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node.`

I can't figure out what's wrong.. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentally switched the order of the arguments passed to [`Node#replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild). The node to be inserted comes before the node to be replaced, somewhat counter-intuitively:

```
tableHolder.replaceChild(table, tableHolder.firstChild);
```

---

### Demo Snippet:

```js
function createTable(row_count, column_count) {
    var table = document.createElement("table"); 

    for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++) {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for (column = 0; column < column_count; column++) {
            let td = document.createElement("td"); 
            td.innerHTML = "a<sub>(" + (row+1) + "," + (column+1) + ")</sub>";
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    table.setAttribute("border", "1");

    var tableHolder = document.getElementById("table-container");
    var oldTable = tableHolder.firstChild;
    if (!oldTable) {
        tableHolder.appendChild(table);
    }
    else {
        //tableHolder.firstChild.replaceWith(table);
        tableHolder.replaceChild(table, tableHolder.firstChild);
    }
}

createTable(10, 10)
```

```html
<div id="table-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please check updated fiddler.there is an update in replace Child.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28302/

```
    tableHolder.replaceChild(table, tableHolder.firstChild);
```